# Confusion about JavaScript Object's method being non-enumerable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
class RandomObject {
  constructor() {
    this.method1 = function() {}
  }

  method2() {
    // only this is non enumerable
  }

  method3 = function() {}
}

const object = new RandomObject()

for (const prop in object) {
  console.log(prop) // 'method1', 'method2'
}
```

I found that only `method1` and `method2` are printed out in the `for...in` loop, meaning they are enumerable. However `method2` doesn't show up in the loop, meaning it is non-enumerable. I wonder what caused the differences here? Why is that only `method2` is non-enumerable in this case?

Also, I found that if I define the method directly in the object literal, then it is enumerable again:

```js
const object2 = {
  method2() {
    // Now this is enumerable
  }
}
```

Comment: `method2` is something that's more realistically a method. And method syntax (which is `method2`) makes it non-enumerable. `method1` and `method3` are both simply instance properties that *happen* to hold a function. But you could have easily made them contain another value like `method1 = "apple"`. I don't think you'd be confused why you can see it in that case. Well, same idea, only your value is a function.

Comment: Lets call a method a function and then since the beginning you have function declarations and function expressions in JS. In your case, in the Class abstraction a function expression (`method3`) becomes an enumerable property of the instantiated object whereas the declaration (`method2`) becomes a prototype function and is not enumerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class prototype methods are non-enumerable - that's just the way the syntax was designed:

```js
class X {
  method() {
  }
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(X.prototype, 'method').enumerable);
```

See [CreateMethodProperty](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createmethodproperty) in [ClassDefinitionEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation), which requires that class methods be non-enumerable.

In contrast, class field syntax - that is, `someProperty = someExpression` *directly inside the class body* - is syntax sugar for running `this.someProperty = someExpression` inside the constructor. Ordinary assignment to a property that doesn't exist on the object yet results in the property being enumerable.

```
class RandomObject {
  method3 = function() {}
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class RandomObject {
  constructor() {
    this.method3 = function() {}
  }
}
```

With methods on ordinary objects, see [PropertyDefinitionEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation), which describes how properties (including methods) get created in object literals. It'll carry out

> Return ? MethodDefinitionEvaluation of MethodDefinition with arguments object and enumerable.

where `enumerable` has been set to `true` with [ObjectLiterals](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation).